# Using file-response from an uberjar

Tags: web-applications, jar, clojure, compojure, ring

Ring's file-response doesn't work for me when running from an uberjar. I've tried both

```
(response/file-response "index.html" {:root "resources/public"})
```

and

```
(response/response (clojure.java.io/as-file (clojure.java.io/resource "public/index.html")))
```

How do you serve index.html at "/" inside an uberjar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use `ring.util.response/resource-response` which serves files found on the classpath. Assuming you want to serve an `index.html` file found inside a `resources` directory in your überjar, the arguments would be almost exactly as in your call to `file-response`:

```
(response/resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"})
```

It's `"public"` as opposed to `"resources/public"`, because `resources` is one of the top-level directories included in the überjar, so `public` will be found on the classpath on the top level. (This would also be true if running from the filesystem instead of an überjar; the path then needs to be relative to some top-level directory on the classpath.)

Comment: Makes sense, but that didn't work for me. I get a 404 when I hit "/". My index.html file is in resources/public, and I haven't defined :resources in my project.clj, so by default it should be the resources/ dir right?

Comment: I should mention `resource-response` returns `Not Found` even when I'm running the app through lein, not just from an uberjar.

Comment: Ah, right, that should be `{:root "public"}`. I'll fix the answer in a second.